# Shiny: set a limit for the input period length using dateRangeInput()

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to somehow limit the input time frame from `dateRangeInput()` in Shiny. What I mean is that whenever the user selects, for example, 2 dates that are more than 3 months apart, Shiny wont let them use it as input and asks them to select 3 months or less. I couldn't use `min` and `max` parameters because i need to limit the period length and not specific dates.

I have tried searching for related questions but couldnt find one that solves this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/updateDateRangeInput.html

Comment: A way of doing this is after the dateRange is specified by the user check in server if the dates are more than 3 months apart. If yes, just return a warning. If not, the user can proceed and use the specified date range.